# Parabolic isometry with fixed point $x=17$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a parabolic isometry that fixes the point $x = 17$.

I know all Möbius transformations with a given fixed point form a matrix group $\{ 1,b;0,1)$, how do I finish?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/368646/28900).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider $$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ with $ad-bc=1.$ If $c\ne 0$, then this transformation has at least one fixed point, and all fixed points will be roots of the quadratic equation $$cz^2-(a-d)z-b=0.$$

The quadratic equation you *want* will be of the form $$0=c(z-17)^2=cz^2-(34c)z+289c$$ Thus, we need $b=289c,$ $a-d=34c$, $a+d=2$ (since we want a parabolic isometry), $ad-bc=1$, and $c\ne 0$. Can you go from there?