# How to finding an elliptic isometry that fixes a point and rotates by an angle?

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

I need to find an elliptic isometry (UHP) that fixes the point $2 + 3i$ and rotates by an angle of $π$

I think I have an idea of how to start but not sure if it is the right one. I was looking at the similar questions and found this question asked earlier [Parabolic isometry with fixed point $x=17$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368716/parabolic-isometry-with-fixed-point-x-17)

I'm confused as how will the method change with the point having an imaginary component instead of just a real value and also how does the roation angle figure into the equation.

Comment: Could you please show us the details of your work so that we can help you to check?

Comment: @Landscape - Unfortunately, I don't have any work to show for atm. Just an idea that may be right, but I'm not sure how to proceed with it. I was looking for more ideas or feedback regarding this idea.

Answer (score 0):

When studying hyperbolic geometry, one should have both the disk model and the halfplane models in mind, and know how to move between them. Use the disk model  when you want to focus on some interior point.

In the disk model, rotation about $0$ by angle $\alpha$ is just the Euclidean rotation: $z$ is mapped to $e^{i\alpha}z$. With $\alpha=\pi$ this is a particularly simple map.

If you can move the given point $a=2+3i$ to $0$ by some hyperbolic isometry $\varphi$ (Möbius map) between the halfplane and the disk, then you will be able to rotate around $0$ as described above, and apply the inverse map $\varphi^{-1}$. The end result will  be $\varphi^{-1}(e^{i\alpha}\varphi(z))$.

The natural choice for $\varphi$ is  $\varphi(z)=\dfrac{z-a}{z-\bar a}$.